# check if the expression is a equation

Tags: expression-manipulation

I need to check if the expression is a correct equation with only 1 variable x and without functions, that are not build into Mathematica.
For example

```
Sin[x]==0
```

is correct equation. And expressions

```
Sin[x*a]==0, Sin[[x]==0, f[x]==0, Exp[x]=9
```

are not correct equations.

Comment: Are you testing these as strings or as expressions? Because one of them sticks out immediately being syntactically incorrect, so _Mathematica_ won't have a problem checking whether it is a well-formed equation or not.

Comment: I'm testing these as strings. When expression is incorrect I will get message. The best variant for me is to get messages in other cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
admissibleEqPat = 
  eq_Equal /; 
   DeleteDuplicates[
     Context /@ 
      DeleteCases[
       Cases[eq, _Symbol, Infinity, 
        Heads -> True], x]] === {"System`"};


MatchQ[x^2 + 3 x == 4 x^2/(x + 2), admissibleEqPat]
(* True *)

MatchQ[Sin[x] == 0, admissibleEqPat]
(* True *)

MatchQ[Sin[a x] == 0, admissibleEqPat]
(* False *)

MatchQ[f[x] == 0, admissibleEqPat]
(* False *)
```

I'm assuming that by built-in functions, you mean the standard built-in ones that are in the `` System` `` context.

Comment: The problem is I need to add all functions, which are possible in my equations to admissibleSymbols.
for example
    MatchQ[Sin[x] == 0, admissibleEqPat]
    (* False *)

Comment: @user10893 Check the update.